# Generating date format column out of three separate columns in Stata

Tags: stata

I have three columns for each observation indicating day, month, and year. I would like to combine these three columns into one to indicate the date. I will later need to add a day or subtracts a day for observations, so I need to make sure the format of the new date column is date.
I'm programming this in Stata. I used mdy function, but it generates empty observations. And I'm not sure why it is not working.

Here is a snapshot of the data:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? [This](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/modules/dates.htm) is a good place to start.

Comment: There is no sign here that you have even tried to read the documentation. "Please tell me the code" questions aren't appropriate here.

Comment: I tried mdy and I was not getting results. However I figured if I just change year values from say 93 to 1993, mdy works fine! so I guess I found the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Stata function mdy should work if the format of "year" is changed from yy to yyyy. Thus we can add 1900 to the "year" variable and then use the function mdy to generate a new variable that indicates the date using three variables "day", "month", and "year". The following code shows how to use mdy function:

```
replace year = 1900+year
gen date = mdy(month,day,year)
```

Comment: Thanks Nick! I like your code better than mine, since it won't replace "year".

Comment: Fine, but you are not changing the format at all, but the values from two-digit calendar years to four-digit calendar years. Format in Stata  means display format as defined by the `format` command.